# 24V optocoupler with 12V?

Tags: power-supply, 12v, 24v

I recently picked up a "[24V Voltage Level Current Converter Module 80KHz 1-Channel Optocoupler Photoelectric Optoisolator 12V PNP NPN Signal Converter PC817 Optocoupler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YJL3MQQ)"

Can I supply this with 12V instead of 24V? If not, is it as simple as changing resistors or do I need a different board?

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us what the value of R1 is on the board?

Comment: Does the LED light up when you power it from 12 V?

Comment: I haven't tried wiring it yet, and it's a 1k (brown, black, red, gold).

Comment: A SWAG.  Assume a 2v drop across the LED which appears to be in series with the Optocoupler and another 2V across the Opto LED. From that you can use the value of the resistor on the board they used for 24V (20 volts for calculations)  then resize it using another that will give the same current with 8 volts. It may work with 12V, you will never know unless you try. A bit of caution as the optocoupler ages its transfer value will decrease as the output of its LED decreases. This is not a short term effect and is dependent on the drive current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the amazon link that you shared. Below is the product image:

[image: pic]

R1 seems to be Brown Green Red Gold resistor which is a 1.5K resistor.

PC817 should work just fine as it is without any change to the circuit. If you face any challenge, try using a lower resistor value for R1. 680 Ohms should do the job.

EDIT:

OP confirmed that resistor is Brown Black Red Gold. It gives a value of 1K. Answer remains same. It should work well.

Comment: Beat me to it. I think it's 1K though (looks black to me, not green).

Comment: Yes it's black.

Comment: Frankly, even I am confused whether its black or green. So, I took the worst case value of 1.5K and saw that it should be fine. :)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Careful assuming that product photos will accurately represent the product! I've seen plenty of cases where the same photo is used for all devices in a range; even on reputable sources like Digi-key I've seen power supplies where the datasheet and description said they were the 12 volt model (and indeed it was the 12 volt model when I received the part), but the product photos were clearly of the 5 volt model!

Comment: @Hearth - valid caution. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Not a problem in this case, of course, as the asker has confirmed that it's a 1 kΩ resistor on the board they physically have! Just a reminder to be careful.