# Short circuit in a level shifter with an optocoupler

Tags: dc-dc-converter, esp32

I saw a similar circuit here (for example):
[24V optocoupler with 12V?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565392/24v-optocoupler-with-12v)

I tried this, but with some extras.

My "extra" was to supply my 12 V sensor with a DC/DC converter ([MT3608](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.es/datasheet-pdf/view/1131968/ETC1/MT3608.html)) from the ESP32 because I need to supply it with a 5 V powerbank.

I have this circuit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Datasheet Barrier

> Asked to vendor (I don't have it yet), the only info that I have is that schematic

So, I'm providing 12 V from the 5 V of the ESP32 (Vin), and then use that 12 V signal in an ESP32 with that optocoupler circuit.

The short circuit appears when I use the NO contact with the black cable (N).

I have connected the white cable (W) to Vout+ too in order to have to have voltage on the contacts.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please give details on the sensor you're using.

Comment: How are  "Vout+" and "Vout -" connected to the sensor?

Comment: Sorry for "corto" its a word used in Spain for it, sorry. My fault. Ok, My sensor, is a photoelectric barrier, 12-24VDC, cables M and A it's for supply the sensor, N is the NO contact of it. Vout+ and Vout- are soldered directly to the sensor's cable

Comment: jairoG - Hi, (a) I see that you haven't read the [tour] - please do that (and the [help]) so that you've seen the main site rules. (b) You said: "*a short circuit appears when I try to use a sensor terminal*" Please [edit] your question to add *much* more explanation of what you mean by a short-circuit *appearing*. How do you know that there's a short-circuit? What do you mean by "try to use a sensor terminal". Use it *how* exactly? (c) Please also add some photos showing (as clearly as possible) your actual hardware & wiring. (d) Why did you label the sensor wires "M", "A", "N" - meaning?

Comment: jairoG - (e) I see you have edited the question, but I will mention another issue which that update has shown. Your sensor has 2 power input wires (brown & blue). You are describing *in words* how you are also connecting to two more wires (white & black) so that is 4 wires used in total. But your schematic shows the sensor has only 3 wires! So either the words or diagram appears to be wrong and is therefore confusing. Please edit your question to clarify (and to respond to my previous points) if you want to help readers to better understand your question). Thanks.

Comment: Your original schematic shows a 470R resistor used in series with the input of the optocoupler, while your new schematic does not have this resistor. You *do need this resistor* (if you use an optocoupler like the PC817! If your actual "as-built" circuit does not have this resistor, then that would explain the short-circuit you're seeing, since you're trying to connect the LED inside the optocoupler directly to 12V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the optocoupler at all.

Just connect the white wire  from the sensor to the ESP32 input (with a pullup) and the black to the ground of the ESP32.

The relay has no connection to power of any sort.  You can use its contacts just like you would use a switch.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJtMov.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relay contacts are already isolated - you do not need the extra isolation provided by the opto-coupler.

Comment: Thats true... I forget that basics of relay, in that way it's to much easy that I did. Thanks a a lot